# Regex doesnt work in java code but on test site

Tags: java, regex

I worked on some regex, which should accept "P1" and "P2" but exactly only those two combinations.
So i tested on this site: http://www.regexr.com/
which lead me to

```
\b(P1)\b|\b(P2)\b
```

The site just gets the right matches.

Appearently the same in my java code won't work:

```
if(commandParameter.matches("\b(P1)\b|\b(P2)\b")){
        return false;
    }
```

As commandParamter i give either P1 or P2. It still doesn't return false.
Have u got any ideas?

Comment: You must escape your ` \ ` in java...

Comment: like @brso05 said, escape your '\'. Else it will be interpreted as '\b' (which is a backspace)

Comment: You can test Java regex patterns at http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/ or [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) .

Comment: @brso05 To write ``\`` surround it with two `\`\`` on both sides like `\`\`\\`\``.

Comment: @Pshemo ok thanks someone told me that before but I forgot the syntax...I can't edit it now but hopefully next time I will remember lol

Answer (score 0):

Note that matches will do an exact match not partial match.

```
if(commandParameter.matches(".*\\bP[12]\\b.*")){
    return false;
}
```

For exact match.

```
if(commandParameter.matches("P[12]")){
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: P[12] works in java but not on the homepage. Why are there Differences? Because of the match method from java?

Comment: @Necator `[12]` should be interpreted same way in all other languages. If it doesn't then problem may not be in regex, but in way you are using it.